# Should I use "extends" on Java POJO to extract common attribute?

Tags: java, orm, pojo, extends

I am using the SQLite ORM on Android to save and query data.

I have some POJOs for ORM, which have several same attributes like "timestamp" among these POJOS.

So should I extract those common attribute into a base class, to **prevent other collaborators from forgetting to use these attributes**? For example,

```
class BaseEvent {
    String activityName;
    //activityName getter and setter
}

class TouchEvent extends BaseEvent {
    int x;
    int y;
    //x and y's getter and setter
    public TouchEvent(int x,int y,String activityName){...}
}

class AccelerationEvent extends BaseEvent {
    float x,y,z;
    public AccelerationEvent (float x,float y,float z,String activityName){...}
}
```

Ignoring the particular ORM(Realm.io), is it a good practice in design pattern?

Comment: I don't know if your ORM would support this; Hibernate does, AFAIK.

Comment: As far as your concern for preventing other collaborators from forgetting to use required attributes then you can do this by providing a constructor which requires all necessary attributes.

Comment: What do you mean by `use`, and what else attributes besides `timestamp`? AFAIK, `timestamp` can be added automatically when you insert records into the database(mysql)

Comment: @ZhaoGang timestamp is just an example. Use means some friends suggest that I shouldn't use extends to reduce the duplication of code on POJO.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this [issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/761) since 2015, we can see that Realm has problems with true polymorphism.

Inheritance in Realm at the moment gets you:

- Class methods, instance methods and properties on parent classes are inherited in their child classes.
- Methods and functions that take parent classes as arguments can operate on subclasses.

So, when you work with Realm, it is highly recommended to use `composition` over `inheritance`.

**EDIT**

Let's re-write your example using composition:

```
interface BaseEvent {}

class TouchEvent implements BaseEvent {}

class AccelerationEvent implements BaseEvent {}

class SomeOfYourClass{
    BaseEvent event;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use it as a design principle there is no harm as such. I have been working with hibernate since last four years and we use this approach in many of our projects to define common attributes such as id and other such fields which will be present in all the tables, however like suggested above you have to check first if your orm supports it.

You can refer below links to get a jist of how its done in hibernate

http://www.devsniper.com/base-entity-class-in-jpa/

https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-inherit-properties-from-a-base-class-entity-using-mappedsuperclass-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: Realm slightly different than Hibernate. First of all, Realm is a MVCC database built from the ground up in C++. MVCC simply means Multiversion Concurrency Control. Afterthat, Realm does not support inheritance. Any realm object must both be inherited from `RealmObject` or implement the `RealmModel` marker interface and be marked with an `@RealmClass` annotation. You cannot inherit from different Realm objects. It is recommended to use the composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: I understand but again if I understand the question correctly, the requestor is seeking more of an advice on the design principle itself asking us to ignore specific realm related concerns...and so is my answer ignoring the same!